# Correlation/relationship between human magnetic field and body temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, temperature

Is there any relationship between human magnetic field and body temperature?

I am looking for studies on this topic.

Comment: All I know is: In the limit of low temperature ($T \rightarrow 0$), the magnetic field emitted by the human body is static. In the limit of high temperature ($T \rightarrow \infty$), the concept of human body is no longer applicable and the human magnetic field is thus no longer well-defined.

Comment: Please elaborate if you want it to be opened.

Comment: The question was stated very clearly, I've already elaborated below one of the answers. I see that on almost every SE forum overall stats are the priority for admins.

Comment: These are not forums, and overall stats (assuming you mean question count) are not the priority; _quality_ is the priority. As it is this is a rather vague question. You could improve it significantly by editing some of the clarifications you made in the comments into the question.

Answer (score 1):

(What I misunderstood as) the question, namely how the body temperature responds to an external magnetic field, is relevant for magnetic resonance imaging/treatment in medicine.

Here are some references:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2948244/

Effect of a 1.5 T static magnetic field on body temperature of man},
Shellock, F.G. et al.,
Magnetic resonance in medicine 3 (1986), 644--647.

Cognitive, cardiac, and physiological safety studies in ultra high field magnetic resonance imaging,
Kangarlu, A. et al.,
Magnetic resonance imaging 17 (1999), 1407--1416.

Comment: I think you're not answering the question: it's not about the effect of external magnetic field on body temperature, but on “human magnetic field” (which apparently is the magnetic field generated by the human body)

Comment: You may be right, but it is difficult to say from such a short question without context. Maybe the question should be put into context; if you are right, I'd like to know why the asker posed the question.

Comment: Yes, by "human magnetic field” I meant the magnetic field generated by the human body. I am curious whether it would be possible to use magnetometer (or some similar device) in order to measure human body temperature and if yes, what precise would it be. From the research I've done I think it can't be done.

Comment: strange question. Why measure it in this indirect way when a direct measurement of temperature is far easier?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score -2):

thank you for thinking outside the box

i think it can be done

take a look on this vid 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnJghb8yk6c&feature=colike

this energy is called **Kirlian** energy refering to a russain scientest

i notice it when i perform ALSALAH "the islamic prayer" cyz my temp increased durinig praying

Comment: Kirlian energy seems to be psuedoscience/fringe to me. If it is, please mark it as such. Here on physics.SE we prefer mainstream, widely accepted physics.